# What's wrong with this simple query using NOT IN?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Schema:

```
radio_bin.id
radio.id
radio.radio_bin -> radio_bin.id
```

Queries:

```
select *
    from radio_bin
```

72 rows.

```
select *
    from radio_bin
    where id in (select radio_bin from radio)
```

50 rows.

(And FWIW:)

```
select distinct radio_bin
    from radio
```

51 rows, including a null.

That's all good.  Now:

```
select *
    from radio_bin
    where id not in (select radio_bin from radio)
```

0 rows.

Why?  Shouldn't I get the 22 radio_bin.id numbers that *don't* have a radio pointing to them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, you have a null value and null is not equal to anything not even another null

```
select *
    from radio_bin
    where id not in (select radio_bin from radio where radio_bin  is not null)
```

See also [NOT IN and NULLS](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/SQL_Server_Programming_Hacks_-_NOT_IN_and_NULLs) which shows you how to use either LEFT JOIN or NOT EXISTS

Comment: I do have one, as indicated in the question, but this does fix it.

Answer (score 2):

change

```
in
```

to

```
Exists
```

Does this work?

See here for an [explanation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/interactive/functions-subquery.html)

Comment: Not directly, it'd have to be `where not exists (select radio_bin from radio where radio.radio_bin = radio_bin.id)`.

Comment: ah yes, ok sorry missed that out but its a good solution as exists doesn't care about nulls.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that `radio_bin.id` is `null`?

If it is the [`NOT IN` does not evaluate to true](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-comparisons.html).

This is because `x NOT IN y` is equivalent to `NOT (x IN y)`.  If `x` is `null` then `(x IN y)` will returns null because nothing is equal to `null`, not even `null`.

Comment: There are no null `radio_bin.id`s.  It's a serial PK.

Answer (score 1):

Because NULLs really muck things up.  The following was run on Oracle but I think this behaviour is standard ANSI SQL behaviour...

```
SQL> select * from t23
  2  where id in ( select id from t42)
  3  /

TXT                                                ID
------------------------------------------ ----------
SAM-I-AM                                            1
KNOX                                                2
FOX                                                 3

SQL> select * from t23
  2  where id not in ( select id from t42)
  3  /

no rows selected

SQL> update t42 set id = 8 where id is null
  2  /

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from t23
  2  where id not in ( select id from t42)
  3  /

TXT                                                ID
------------------------------------------ ----------
LORAX                                               9

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using NOT IN, if you plan to SCALE up this query substantially.  If you are talking about a small application it shouldn't be a problem,  but if you are talking about millions of rows (even potentially) avoid this approach!

> Negative operations, such as <> or NOT
>   LIKE, are also very difficult to
>   resolve efficiently. Try to rewrite
>   them in another way if you can. If you
>   are only checking for existence, use
>   the IF EXISTS or the IF NOT EXISTS
>   construct instead. You can use an
>   index. If you use a scan, you can stop
>   the scan at the first occurrence.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998577.aspx